# Is there a way to have a timer running in the background that pauses when I shut my laptop? (trying to measure battery life)

Tags: power-management, battery

Essentially what I'd like to do is use my laptop normally and just have a sort of timer in the background. I will charge my battery to full, and then nearly drain it.

I would like for there to be some sort of stopwatch in the background that's running until I decide to stop it when it's nearly dead. I would like for it to pause whenever I shut the lid on my laptop, and start again when I open it. Is this achievable?

Comment: I think it is possible as long as you don't shutdown the laptop. I don't know whether there is an existing utility but someone can right a script for this...

Comment: Yeah I wondered if I could execute a script. I am not sure what I would need to write to make that happen. It would need to stay active for as long as I am doing the test.

Comment: I think you can also achieve what you want through the Power Statistics app

Comment: I saw that recommended, but there is no information on the x-y scatter graph. It should show the power percentage level, and time elapsed. Older pictures of the app show this so it's kind of confusing.

Comment: What do you mean? It is clear enough in the History tab. Y axis show the percentage and X axis shows the time. If you want it to be more detailed, you can change the time shown in the graph. Change the graph type dropdown to "Time to empty"

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by the "Power Statistics" app.

It is clear enough in the History tab. Change the graph type dropdown to "Time to empty" Y-axis shows the percentage and X-axis shows the time it took to discharge. If you want it to be more detailed, you can change the time shown in the graph.